# Fastest randomized algorithm for trace distance

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, randomized-algorithms

Assume to have query access to the values $p(x)$, and $q(x)$ of two probability distributions over n elements $x \in X$, $|X|=n$.
That is, for a given $x\in X$ we pay constant time $O(1)$ to perform a query to $p$ or $q$.

What is the fastest randomized algorithm for estimating the trace distance between $p$ and $q$? Formally, I would like to know the fastest algorithm in literature to estimate $\widetilde{T}$ such that $|T-\widetilde{T}|<\epsilon$ with probability $1-\delta$ where $T$ is:

$$T = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{x \in X} |p(x) -q(x)| $$

I am looking for all the type of cases: average time, worst time.. I would ready any paper that is relevat to this question, so to understand when it's important to estimate trace distances.

Comment: How do you measure "fastest"?  Worst-case running time?  Average-case?  If so, what distribution on distributions do you have in mind?  Something else?

Comment: Good question. I think any setting is relevant, as I am trying to learn more about where trace distance is used in practice.

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ the probability mass functions? Then you can't do faster than $O(n)$ (unless you allow very high error probability): consider two distributions where $p_i = 1$ for some $i$ and $q_j =1$ for some $j$. You need to check whether $i=j$, and for that you need to find at least one of them. There is no way to do this faster than $O(n)$.

Comment: "I want to know for all types of cases..." doesn't help.  This site is intended for focused, specific question.  Each one of those cases has some issues; by trying to tackle them all, it makes it hard to provide a useful answer.  I'm trying to get you to focus on just one for now so that I can highlight the issues associated with that.  I already indicated that if you want average-case, you need to specify a distribution on distributions; I don't see that you have addressed that.  Dmitry is highlighting an issue for worst-case running time.  Please pick one notion of running time.